# C# XML List of Multiple Types

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I am pulling some data from a 3rd party web service that is very complex.  The XSD tool doesn't work on the particular schema so I am attempting to manually build all the data objects.

```
<Children>
    <Activity></Activity>
    <Activity></Activity>
    <Container></Container>
    <Activity></Activity>
    <Container></Container>
    ...
</Children>
```

Essentially each item in the Collection can either be an Activity or a Container but not both.

I am attempting to use the XmlSerializer in C# to Serialize/Deserialize the Xml and I have an object library backing the Serializer that currently looks like so:

```
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
public class Children: XmlEntityBase, IChildren
{
 [XmlElement("Children", IsNullable = false)]
 public List<ChildrenItems> ChildrenItems { get; } = new List<ChildrenItems>();
}

[XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
public class ChildrenItem: XmlEntityChoice, IChildrenItem
{
 [NotMapped]
 [XmlElement(nameof(Activity), Type = typeof(Activity), IsNullable = false)]
 [XmlElement(nameof(Container), Type = typeof(Container), IsNullable = false)]
 public object SelectedValue
 {
  get { return _selectedValue; }
  set 
  { 
   if(_selectedValue == value) return;
    SetValue(value);
  }
 }

 [XmlIgnore]
 public Activity Activity 
 {
  get 
  {
   if(ValueType == typeof(Activity))
   {
    return (Activity)SelectedValue;
   }
   throw new ChoiceTypeException($"Invalid Type: {nameof(Activity)}!");
  }
 }

 [XmlIgnore]
 public Container Container
 {
  get
  {
   if(ValueType == typeof(Container)
   {
    return (Container)SelectedValue;
   }
   throw new ChoiceTypeException($"Invalid Type: {nameof(Container)}!");
  }
 }
}
```

ChildrenItem is my attempt at coding a xsd:choice in XML.

Unfortunately, when I DeSerialize the XML from the WebService the Children collection is skipped.

1) How do I fix my objects so that they properly handle the XML?
2) Is there a better way to handle xsd:choice elements than the way I am doing so here?

Thanks and have a very Blessed Day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all you really need.  Don't use array becaused it create an extra lay of tags which will not work in your case.  XmlElement will work with arrays or lists.

```
    [XmlRoot("Children")]
    public class Children
    {
        [XmlElement("Activity")]
        List<Activity> activity { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Container")]
        List<Container> container { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot("Activity")]
    public class Activity
    {

    }
    [XmlRoot("Container")]
    public class Container
    {

    }
```

Comment: Just a note.  It is easier to serialize the code to verify your classes and then compare the serialized xml against to xml you are attempting to read.  If the classes serialize properly they should deserialize also.